# gcloud beta functions command says "Invalid choice functions"

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm following the google cloud functions tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart

I install `google-cloud-sdk` and source both `path.bash.inc` and `completion.bash.inc`.

The `gsutil` command step works and creates the storage bucket.

When I run `gcloud beta functions deploy helloWorld --stage-bucket [BUCKET_NAME] --trigger-topic hello_world` replacing with my [BUCKET_NAME] I get usage help and the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta) Invalid choice: 'functions'.

Valid choices are [app, auth, bigtable, compute, config, container, dataflow, dataproc, debug, deployment-manager, emulators, error-reporting, iam, init, logging, ml, organizations, projects, pubsub, service-management, source, sql, test].
```

I'm not sure how the gcloud command works, but I can see the `functions` directory in the `lib/surface/` directory of the `google-cloud-sdk`.

Why does `gcloud beta functions` not work? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest cloud SDK installed.

I got the same error and it seems I had version 137 while the latest is 152.

After running `gcloud components update` it was solved.

Comment: I can't believe that worked. I was facing this issue with "gcloud firestore..." and I literally just downloaded gcloud on my linux box just a few months ago. After I ran this, it instantly worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The functions are in subscription-only beta phase right now. From [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart):

> **Beta**
>
> This is a Beta release of Google Cloud Functions. This API might be
>   changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not subject to any SLA or
>   deprecation policy.
>
> **Want to get advance access to the latest and greatest? Click [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud-functions-beta-testers) to become a beta tester.**

The `gcloud` cmd *might* be checking beta subscriptions. Did you subscribe?

Also make sure you have the most recent cloud SDK version.

Comment: I did subscribe, and in fact, it works fine on my linux server. I had the issue on my macos desktop.

Comment: Hm, maybe an OS-specific SDK support issue? I imagine there is no point in suggesting to check if you used the same user account in authentication :)

Comment: :)  Yes same user account and same project.