# Dataproc clusters create says invalid choice enable component gateway

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to create a cluster via Google Cloud Shell (not the SDK, didn't download anything) and I am using the same command that works well for many of my classmates, but I am getting an "invalid choice" error (see below). I have tried both `gcloud beta dataproc clusters create` and without beta as shown in the image below. Probably some arguments are not needed anymore today, or are not the most up-to-date, like the zone and so on, but that does not seem to be the cause of the error... Any ideas?

This is related to [gcloud beta functions command says "Invalid choice functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916677/gcloud-beta-functions-command-says-invalid-choice-functions) but the author was using the SDK, which I am not using, and the answer was to use the latest version.

[image]

Comment: Google Cloud CLI is part of Cloud SDK. You can access [Google Cloud CLI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBU_tF7UzQY) using the cloud shell. As mentioned in stack link you have shared, you and check the sdk version using the command `gcloud version` and run the command `gcloud components update`.